# c++ wiggle sort II soln

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

https://leetcode.com/problems/wiggle-sort-ii/description/
THis the problem.

I have tried to sort it using the sort function and by defining my own custom comaparator, I didn't able to undestand where I am wrong. please help.

```
class Solution {
public:
 int cnt=0;
static bool comp( int a, int b)
{
    if(cnt%2)
    {
        cnt++;
     return a>b;
    }
    else{
        cnt++;
     return a<b;   
    }
}
    void wiggleSort(vector<int>& nums) {

       sort(nums.begin(),nums.end(),comp);
       return nums; 
    }
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to create a [mre]. And make your questions *self contained* (without the *need* to use external links to understand your problem).

Comment: As a likely part of your problem, the [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) function, and any ordering at all in C++, requires the ordering function to satisfy [some requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare). The most important is that it's adhering to [the strict weak ordering relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings). Which your ordering function doesn't.

Comment: `std::sort` will chop up the range into subranges, and sort these separately. It will not do a single pass from begin to end.

Comment: DSA stands for Digital Signature Algorithm. Please don't add irrelevant tags. If in doubt, read tag description before you add it.

Answer (score 2):

Oops... There are different kinds of problem here. And a decent compiler should have warned you about some of them.

1. C++ syntax

   - minor: `void wiggleSort(...)` returns a value. This is just nonsense: you are promising the compiler that `wiggleSort` does not return anything, yet using `return` in the function. It should be ignored by any common compiler, but the code is anyway invalid. Solution: just remove the useless and offending `return nums;`.
   - major: you are using a non static member inside a static function.
     Here a decent compiler should raise a compilation error. Workaround: make `cnt` static in the `Solution` class:

     ```
       class Solution {
       public:
           static int cnt;     // declare a static member
           ...
       };
       int Solution::cnt = 0;  // initialize the static member...
     ```
   - major: the third parameter of the `std::sort` function is expected to take its parameters *by reference*. Here its signature should be:

     ```
       bool comp(const int& a, const int& b) {
           ...
       }
     ```

     This was the easy part, and the first 2 points could have been avoided by using a decent compiler.
2. Logical:

   The comparison function is expected to provide a [strict weak ordering relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings). Specifically *transitivity is required*. As your function does not respect transitivity, you cannot use it in `std::sort`

   This is the hard part here. Because it means that your solution is flawed from its concept level. You just have to find a different approach.

Last but not least: **please do not use leetcode or similar sites to learn C++ or improve your c++ knowledge**. Those sites only require that your program *give the expected result on one single C++ implementation*. This is the best way to learn how to:

- write code invoking Undefined Behaviour that happen to provide the expected result... but would crash or worse give wrong results in a different context
- write *spaghetti* or unmaintainable code
- more generally, never respect best practices

If you really want to become a good programmer, learn through good books (you should find some on this site [C++ tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info). And as soon as you have some working code, ask for review on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get *experts* advices on it.